# Can't see the image directly need a refresh

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

When I use this function to create the image with specified link its not showing directly 
After a refresh it is appearing

http://mysite.local/img/slide-image-321.jpg/369x360

is the link for the image

```
private function generate_cache($localpath, $from, $to, $width, $height) {
        $tempFrom = pathinfo($from);
        $tempTo = pathinfo($to);
        $tempPathFrom = $localpath.$tempFrom['basename'];
        $tempPathTo = $localpath.$tempTo['basename'];
        // Amazon S3
        $awsAccessKey =  Zend_Registry::getInstance()->config->amazons3->awsAccessKey;
        $awsSecretKey = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->config->amazons3->awsSecretKey;
        $bucketName = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->config->amazons3->bucketName;
        $s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);
        // ..
        if(file_get_contents('http://'.$bucketName.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$tempFrom['basename'])) {
            $content = file_get_contents('http://'.$bucketName.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$tempFrom['basename']);
        }

        if(!file_put_contents($tempPathFrom, $content)){
            echo "Failed to copy the file";
        }

        $resize = $this->_helper->imgResize($tempPathFrom);
        $resize->resizeImage($width, $height);
        $resize->saveImage($tempPathTo, 95);


            if(!$s3->putFile($tempPathTo, $bucketName."/".$tempTo["basename"])){
            echo "failed to put the resized image in s3";
        } else {
            // Deleting the local files
            unlink($tempPathTo);
            unlink($tempPathFrom);

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when your page is loading, the image won't be created at the server. Actually it may be created before you refresh and will be shown after refresh.

Comment: when I work with only server (Not amazon s3 ) its working fine, problem is with s3, I don't know how to fix it

 private function generate_cache($from, $to, $width, $height)         {
  $resize = $this->_helper->imgResize($from);
  $resize->resizeImage($width, $height);
  $resize->saveImage($to, 95);
}

Comment: Not sure I am showing you the right way, but when trying s3 it may take time to process the image and if its on the server itself, the image will be processed instantaneously .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I moved the last uploading to s3 part to here, for the first time its loading from local and I am uploading it to s3 and deleting local and when they refresh or for second time it loads from s3

```
    if( file_exists($localpath.$tmp["basename"]) ) {
                readfile($localpath.$tmp["basename"]);
                self::upload_aws($localpath.$tmp["basename"], $bucketName."/".$tmp["basename"]);
            } elseif($s3->getObject($bucketName."/".$tmp["basename"])){
                echo $s3->getObject($bucketName."/".$tmp["basename"]);
    }



public function upload_aws(){
     if(!$s3->putFile($tempPathTo, $bucketName."/".$tempTo["basename"])){
                echo "failed to put the resized image in s3";
            } else {
                // Deleting the local files
                unlink($tempPathTo);
                unlink($tempPathFrom);

     }


}
```